# Unable to modify .content.xml of new cq:dialog node in AEM 6.5

Tags: aem, sling, aem-6, filevault

I am trying to create a custom component in AEM 6.5. I am following [this](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/getting-started-wknd-tutorial-develop/custom-component.html?lang=en#create-sling-model) link. I have created a new cq:dialog node under byline component but i am unable to modify it's .content.xml file, the 'show in editor' option is disabled.

[image]

Comment: Can you please expand the cq:dialog and double click on the content node and try.

Comment: Does the same happen if you try to edit directly in the CRXDE?

Comment: i could see the jcr properties of the node..but didnt try to add manually one by one as the lines of code was long for that dialog

Answer (score 0):

select your Project
then click on window->show view->Navigator

[image]